# как сделать телеграм бота приемом заявок на pyTelegramBotAPI

Tags: python, telebot

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot('')


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    user_markup = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True)
    user_markup.row('Запись', 'Кол.занятий', 'Абонемент')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Здраствуйте', reply_markup=user_markup)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def handle_test(message):
    if message.text == 'Запись':
        user_markup = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True)
        user_markup.row('Понедельник', 'Суббота')
        user_markup.row('Вторник', 'Пятница', '/start')
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Дни для записи', reply_markup=user_markup)

    elif message.text == 'Кол.занятий':
        user_markup = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True)
        user_markup.row('/start')
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Оставшееся количество занятий', reply_markup=user_markup)

    elif message.text == 'Абонемент':
        user_markup = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True)
        user_markup.row('/start')
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Преобрести абонемент https://www.tinkoff.ru/rm/yakovlev.artur28/DWEAe82692',
                         reply_markup=user_markup)

    elif message.text == 'Понедельник':
        user_markup = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True)
        user_markup.row('/start', 'Да понедельник')
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вы уверены?', reply_markup=user_markup)

    elif message.text == 'Вторник':
        user_markup = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True)
        user_markup.row('/start', 'Да вторник')
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вы уверены?', reply_markup=user_markup)

    elif message.text == 'Пятница':
        user_markup = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True)
        user_markup.row('/start', 'Да пятница')
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вы уверены?', reply_markup=user_markup)

    elif message.text == 'Суббота':
        user_markup = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True)
        user_markup.row('/start', 'Да суббота')
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вы уверены?', reply_markup=user_markup)


bot.infinity_polling()
```

Comment: https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/step_example.py

Comment: Спасибо stawdog

Answer (score 0):

Используй вместо всех этих жутких условий функцию под КАЖДЫЙ случай. У тебя он message не обновляет.

```
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.text=='ожидаемый от пользователя текст')
def functionName():
   pass
```

Не факт, что это то, что нужно, но очень непонятно сформулирован вопрос, в следующий раз пиши поконкретней.